# How do you assign co-leaders?

Tags: clash-of-clans

As a leader, how do I assign co-leaders? Can a co-leader be demoted?

Answer (score 10):

Once you promote someone to *Elder* you can then promote them to *Co-Leader*. To promote someone you have to go to your clan Screen to see all of the people in your clan. Then tap on someone you want to promote and you will see this option pop-up. If they are not yet an *Elder* you will see an option to make then an *Elder*. Choose that button and press "Ok" in the popup that follows and the person will now be a *Elder*

[image: Promote to elder]

Once you promote them to *Elder*, you can do the same process but then you will see "Promote to Co-Leader" instead. Choose that button and press "Ok" in the popup that follows and the person will now be a *Co-Leader*

[image: Promote to co-leader]

If you want to "Demote" someone follow the same procedure except now you can choose the "Demote To" button that will take them down one level each time until they are only a *member*.

Comment: And probably via the same menu. you can demote them to Elder or Member (for the second question)

Comment: You can Promote Elders to Co-Leader even if you are a Co-Leader yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using your authority to promote someone must be done wisely.

To do so, follow these steps:

- Click on their icon name
- Select "Promote to Elder", and confirm (Yes)
- Click on their icon name again.
- Select "Promote to Co-leader", and confirm (Yes)

Obviously you won't need to follow the first two steps if they are already an Elder.

If you are the leader,you have the authority to demote co-leaders, which is under the promote option.